# Finding and Filling Missing Observations (Whole Rows not NA Values) with Mean Values

Tags: r, missing-data, data-cleaning

I am hoping to get some help identifying:

1. The location of missing observations when no NA values are present
   (entire row is missing).
2. Create a row for the missing data with mean values based on mean values from certain categories.

My df:

- Numerical load data from hockey players during practices over the season
- Occasionally the accelerometers do not work during practice even though the player practiced. So to make sure we can still track the work they did during practice, I would like to insert the average mean value from their position (forward, defense, or goalie) from that practice. (i.e. if a goalie’s accelerometer does not work I would like to take the average loads of the other goalies and insert it into that player’s observational row for the practice).
- This would be a simpler task if there were rows ALL players each practice and NA values for loads when the accelerometer doesn’t work BUT when I download the data in a csv from the online cloud there are only rows for players who had working units. So that part is out of my control.

```
> head(DummyLoads)  
 Name       Date Load Position    
1   Jim 2019-10-19  900    2.100  Forward 
2   Bob 2019-10-19  900    2.100  Forward 
3  Dave 2019-10-19  900    2.100  Forward 
4 Steve 2019-10-19  850    2.312  Forward 
5  Fred 2019-10-19  850    2.312  Defense 
6   Ray 2019-10-19  850    2.312  Defense
```

```
DummyLoads <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L),
 .Label = c("Bob",  "Dave", "Fred", "Jim", "Ray", "Steve"), 
class = "factor"), 
Date = structure(c(1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
.Label = c("2019-10-19", "2019-10-20", "2019-10-21",  "2019-10-22"), class = "factor"), 
Load = c(900L, 900L, 900L,  850L, 850L, 850L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 960L, 960L, 909L, 909L, 909L,  991L, 991L, 991L, 720L, 717L, 717L, 717L), 
Load.Min = c(2.1,  2.1, 2.1, 2.312, 2.312, 2.312, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 2, 2, 1.88,  1.88, 1.88, 1.99, 1.99, 1.99, 2.1, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3), Position = structure(c(2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
.Label = c("Defense", "Forward"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -21L))
```

```
ggplot(DummyLoads, aes(x = Name, y = Load, fill = Position))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  facet_grid(~Date)
```

Here is a chart showing players with missing data.

[Missing Player Loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxyMe.png)

Ideally I would like to be able to identify those missing data points without having to plot it first. I also want to avoid having to manually calculate means each time and then input. Hoping to find an automated solution because I will have a full season of practices to do this with, but understand that might be tricky!

Thank you in advance for any suggestions. I apologize if I didn’t explain things clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to the current question:

```
DummyLoads <- DummyLoads %>% 
  ungroup()
full_data <- expand.grid(
  Athlete = DummyLoads %>% 
    pull(Athlete) %>% 
    unique(),
  Date = DummyLoads %>% 
    pull(Date) %>% 
    unique())


full_data %>% 
  # join incomplete data onto full data
  left_join(DummyLoads, by = c("Athlete", "Date")) %>% 
  # assign the position to each player
  # in the example data, some players do ahve different positions
  # if this is true, than it would be unclear which average should be
  # considered. Therefore, I assumed their position is constant
  left_join(DummyLoads %>% 
              select(Athlete, Position) %>% 
              distinct(Athlete, .keep_all=TRUE),
            by = "Athlete") %>% 
  # keep both to check the differences
  rename(Position = Position.y) %>% 
  group_by(Date, Position) %>% 
  # if Load is missing, take the mean of Loads which is grouped
  mutate(Load2 = coalesce(PL_Avg, 
                          mean(PL_Avg, na.rm = T)))
```

Comment: Sorry about the mistake in my dummy dataframe. I have edited my original post with a correct example. Yes you are correct the positions would not change! I'll give this a shot and report back!

Comment: Gave it a shot but ran into this error:

Adding missing grouping variables: `Date`
Error: Column `Date` is unknown
Any idea what I may have done incorrectly?

Comment: Please check whether you used exactly the same data as provided above. I include it in my solution.

Comment: Ah yes that worked perfectly! When I use my actual data I get the error above. I'm not sure if it's due to how my data is grouped? I'll see if I can post my actual df for a week.

Comment: Added to my original question!

Comment: your df was grouped and therefore the `select`in the second join did not work properly. I updated the code

Comment: Yes amazing! Worked perfectly. The grouped df has messed me up before too. Thank you so much. I was even just able to add another column using mutate and the positional averages for the other variable too. I clicked the checkmark for you!

Comment: I added a twist on the question with another layer of complexity if you're able to take a look and build off the solution you already nailed.

Answer (score 0):

Generic Base R solution:

```
# Mark out NA rows flatten in single observation (each element denoting a vector of the df):

    is_val_na <- apply(data.frame(lapply(DummyLoads,

                                         function(x){is.na(x)})), 1, paste, collapse = ", " )

    # Split up using the grouping var "Name", and impute the mean where NA, coerce list to df: 

    DummyLoads_imputed <- do.call("rbind", lapply(split(DummyLoads, DummyLoads$Position), 
                              function(x){
                                if(is.numeric(x)){
                                  ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), x)
                                  }else{x}
                                }
                              )
                            )

    # Bind the data.frame with a factor vector holding the T/F values: 

    DummyLoads_imputed <- cbind(DummyLoads_imputed, row_na = as.factor(is_val_na))
```

Data Used:

```
DummyLoads <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L), 
                                          .Label = c("Bob",  "Dave", "Fred", "Jim", "Ray", "Steve"),
                                          class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
                                                                                3L, 3L, 3L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("2019-10-19", "2019-10-20", "2019-10-21",  "2019-10-22"), 
                                                                              class = "factor"), Load = c(900L, 900L, 900L,  850L, 850L, 850L, 789L, 789L, 789L, 960L, 
                                                                                                          960L, 909L, 909L, 909L,  991L, 991L, 991L, 720L, 717L, 717L, 717L), 
                         Position = structure(c(2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
                                              .Label = c("Defense", "Forward"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA,  -21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sorry about the mistake in my dummy dataframe. I have edited my original post with a correct example. Yes you are correct the positions would not change! I'll give this a shot and report back!

Comment: Hi @VickiB if you found this useful please upvote and if it answers your question please accept it as an answer !

Comment: So when I ran this I got a new column called "row_na" that listed "FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE." It didn't seem to add any rows for the missing observations. Any thoughts?

Comment: That’s what it does in the first expression. It tells you which Columns value is NA in that row. So if your second column had an NA in that row and all other columns had values it would read “FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE”. The second expression imputes the groupwise mean (by position) value (excluding NAs from the computation) into a row where the value is NA. So you can know what values have had their mean imputed in which rows while all NA values have been replaced with the means of each respective position.

Comment: @VickiB did you find this useful ? If you did please leave a like - there is no payment for the help you receive other than your appreciation via the liking and acceptance method.